# Replace USB port with USB cable RPi Model A

Tags: usb, electronics

Is it possible to remove the USB port on a model a and solder on a 4 wire USB cable? I know that theoretically it is possible but does anyone have any experience actually doing this?

If anyone has done this before do you also know which connector (on the RPi at the base of the USB port) is which (VCC, GND, DATA1, DATA2)?

Comment: Perhaps you can explain _why_ you'd want to, rather than just plugging a cable into the port - is it just a question of space? Also, please clarify you mean the full-size USB socket, not the micro USB (power) socket, right?

Comment: yeah its a question of space and a full USB socket so using both the data pins as well as the power pins on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible by looking at the USB Female pinouts.
If you can splice the wires and get them connected in the same order as they were on the male plug, it should work just fine.
I have verified this on my Model B (Only difference is 8 pins instead of four) and it works fine.

For the pin order, flip over the raspberry pi and make the connector for the USB face downwards. From left to right, VCC, D-, D+ and GND.

Hope this helped you.

Comment: You could also refer to [wikipedia's image of the plug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:USB.svg) if the board connectors are in the same order.